# How to convert three functions to one generic function?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have three getColors functions in the below sample.

**Question :** How to convert threee getcolors functions to one generic function?

```
struct EcvColorMap{
    vector<Scalar> getColors(){
        vector<Scalar> result;
        //....
        return result;
    }
};
struct Scalar{
   int val[3];
};

    vector<Scalar> getColors(vector<Scalar> colors){
        return colors;
    }
    vector<Scalar> getColors(Scalar color){
        return{ color };
    }
    vector<Scalar> getColors(EcvColorMap color_map){
        return color_map.getColors();
    }
```

Comment: You can make a generic one and specialize it as needed, but these are pretty different and you'd probably better off just having three functions.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Having those three overloads looks like the correct design here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: the bodies of the functions are different and if you tried to make a generic one and have the others partially specialized and completely specialized like

```
template<typename T> vector<Scalar> getColors(T colors) {
    return {colors};
}

//template<typename T> vector<Scalar> getColors(vector<T> colors) { // Not really necessary - see list initialization
//  return colors;
//}

template<> vector<Scalar> getColors<EcvColorMap>(EcvColorMap colors) {
    return colors.getColors();
}
```

you still would have to write the code for three different templates for no gain at all (where's the compile-time advantage or code reuse?).

My personal advice: **don't use templates just because it's cool, use them when actually needed**. In a huge-software view, this is crucial. The design you posted makes sense to me.

Comment: `getColors(vector<T> colors)` is unnecessary, `getColors(T colors)` handles constructing a `vector<Scalar>` from `vector<T>`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious that's right, I need to study C++11 better, initialization lists can also call copy constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert these functions, this is as clear as it gets.

Your three functions have different bodies, so you can't put them in a single template function. You can replace them with a template function, with specializations for these types, but it would only complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Marco's answer, you'd have to weigh the pros and cons of using templates in this case.

That been said, you could check a typical approach, using traits; this is typically done when you want to **abstract out things that can happen in different ways**. So you could dispatch the actual **getter** like so :

```
template<typename T>
vector<Scalar> getColors(T colors)
{
    return getter<T>::get(colors); 
}
```

Then you'd build some **traits** for each of your entities

```
template<typename T>
struct getter; // types not specified in your traits system will not work

template<>
struct getter<vector<Scalar>> {
    static vector<Scalar> get(vector<Scalar> colors) { 
        return colors; 
    }
};

template<>
struct getter<Scalar> {
    static vector<Scalar> get(Scalar color) { 
        return { color }; 
    }
};

template<>
struct getter<EcvColorMap> {
    static vector<Scalar> get(EcvColorMap color) { 
        return color_map.getColors(); 
    }
};
```

No magic there, you still have to manually write all the code. **The only case this would be any good** is if you'd have to use **getter** in many more places, so you'd be able to always write :

```
template<typename T>
void FunctionN(T arg)
{
    auto val = getter<T>::get(arg); 
    // do stuff like printing etc
}
```

So the bigger N gets the more you gain from abstracting out the `get` operation. Similarly a `set` operation could be divised etc etc ..

Answer (score 0):

The first two functions use the types `Scalar` and `vector<Scalar>` both of which can be used to constructor a `vector<Scalar>`. You can reduce these to one function that supports any type convertible to either `Scalar` or `vector<Scalar>`.

```
template <class T>
std::vector<Scalar> getColors(const T& data)
{
    return { data };
}

// Overloads do not need to be a template.
std::vector<Scalar> getColors(const EcvColorMap& data)
{
    return { data.getColors() };
}
```

To eliminate the final `getColors` function (and if it makes sense) you can provide an explicit conversion operator in `EcvColorMap`. This will allow instances of `EcvColorMap` to be passed to the version of `getColors` shown above..

```
struct EcvColorMap
{
    explicit operator std::vector<Scalar>() const
    {
        std::vector<Scalar> result;
        //....
        return result;
    }
};
```

With the above two changes you can now call `getColors` for all the types listed in your question.

```
std::vector<Scalar> colors;
Scalar color;
EcvColorMap colormap;

getColors(color);
getColors(colors);
getColors(colormap);
```

If providing the conversion operator makes sense you can eliminate the `getColors` functions through construction and assignment.

```
std::vector<Scalar> colors;
Scalar color;

// Construct
std::vector<Scalar> new_colors1{color};
std::vector<Scalar> new_colors2{colors};

// Assign.
std::vector<Scalar> new_colors;
new_colors = colors;
new_colors = { color };
new_colors = colormap.getColors();
```